# Ошибка при обработке нажатия на кнопку

Tags: android

У моей Activity есть SnackBar, в котором в свою очередь находится кастомный Layout. В этом Layout находятся кнопки, которые мне нужно обрабатывать, но когда я пытаюсь присвоить обработчик вылетает ошибка. Кнопка находится в R.layout.snackbar

Метод onCreate()

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reader);

    bottomBar = Snackbar.make(cl, "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);
    Snackbar.SnackbarLayout btmBarLayout = (Snackbar.SnackbarLayout) bottomBar.getView();
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View snackView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.snackbar, null);
    snackView.setBackgroundColor(323232);
    btmBarLayout.addView(snackView, 0);

    rotate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rotate);
    rotate.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы должны искать кнопку в снэкбаре а не где-то там еще -

```
rotate = (Button)snackView.findViewById(R.id.rotate);
```

И

`setOnClickListener(this)` означает, что вы хотите присвоить слушатель как переопределенный метод `onClick` интерфейса `OnClickListener`, то есть вам надо либо

Унаследовать активность от `OnClicklistener` и реализовать его метод `onClick`, либо создать слушатель самому

```
rotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick(View v){
// что будет при нажатии?
}
});
```

не рекомендуется программно устанавливать полноэкранный режим, лучше в `styles.xml` укажите родительскую тему c постфиксом `NoActionBar.Fullscreen`

```
@android:style/Theme.Holo/Material/AppCompat.NoActionBar.Fullscreen
```

Comment: С первым спасибо.
Ниже у меня есть метод onClick(), я его код просто не скинул.

Comment: Через стили пытался утановить, но у меня вылетала ошибка, так что пришлось программно фуллскрин делать

Comment: какие ошибки вылетали? у вас AppCompatActivity?

Comment: Да, неизвестная ошибка, программа сразу вылетала при запуске.

Comment: Если надо - могу дополнительно помочь со стилями у меня эппкомпат и фуллскрин работает

Comment: Лучше подскажите, как программно убрать фуллскрин